# How to factorize and solve equations with $\Sigma$ notation?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus, summation, summation-method

I have a few doubts about the properties of sigma notation, $\Sigma$ . My questions rely on factorization and solving equations with $\Sigma$.On account of the fact that my questions are correlated, I will keep them in this single post rather than different posts. It is also important to note that I have read other questions here, however, these did not help me.

First. Suppose that we have the following expression,

$\displaystyle\left(\sum_{j=0}^{N}y^{j}\left(\sum_{i=0}^{j}k^{i}\,i\,\displaystyle A_{i,j-i}\right)\right)^{2}+\left(\sum_{j=0}^{N}y^{j}\left(\sum_{i=0}^{j}k^{i}\,i\,\displaystyle B_{i,j-i}\right)\right)^{2}$.

Is it allowed to factorize the first term,$\sum_{j=0}^{N}y^{j}$, from both expressions?

That is to say,

$\displaystyle\left(\sum_{j=0}^{N}y^{j}\left(\sum_{i=0}^{j}k^{i}\,i\,\displaystyle A_{i,j-i}\right)\right)^{2}+\left(\sum_{j=0}^{N}y^{j}\left(\sum_{i=0}^{j}k^{i}\,i\,\displaystyle B_{i,j-i}\right)\right)^{2}$

$=\displaystyle\left(\sum_{j=0}^{N}y^{j}\right)^{2}\left[\left(\sum_{i=0}^{j}k^{i}\,i\,\displaystyle A_{i,j-i}\right)^{2}+\left(\sum_{i=0}^{j}k^{i}\,i\,\displaystyle B_{i,j-i}\right)^{2}\right]$

$=\displaystyle\left(\frac{y^{N+1}}{y-1}-\frac{1}{y-1}\right)^{2}\left[\left(\sum_{i=0}^{j}k^{i}\,i\,\displaystyle A_{i,j-i}\right)^{2}+\left(\sum_{i=0}^{j}k^{i}\,i\,\displaystyle B_{i,j-i}\right)^{2}\right]$?

Second. It is already well-known that
$\displaystyle\left(\sum_{j=0}^{N}x_{j}\right)^2=\sum_{j=0}^{N}(x_{j})^{2}+\sum_{m<j}^{N}x_{j}\,x_{m}$.

Nevertheless, how should I proceed if the squared summation  has a product of terms, i.e. $\displaystyle\left(\sum_{i=0}^{j}\,\,k^{i}\,\,i\,\,\displaystyle A_{i,j-i}\right)^{2}$?

Third. How may one solve the equation $\left(\sum_{i=0}^{j}k^{i}\,i\,\displaystyle A_{i,j-i}\right)^{2}+\left(\sum_{i=0}^{j}k^{i}\,i\,\displaystyle B_{i,j-i}\right)^{2}=0$
for $k$?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I suggest that the best way to think about these kinds of expressions is to write out terms with ellipses, rather than thinking about rules. So $(\sum_{i=0}^n x_i)^2 = (x_0 + x_1 + \cdots + x_n)^2$. Multiply that out.

Comment: Alternatively, it might help to replace such expressions or parts of them by a single symbol to make it easier to see. For instance, for your first question, replace $\sum_{i=0}^{j}k^{i}\,i\,\displaystyle A_{i,j-i}$ with $S(j)$ and $\sum_{i=0}^{j}k^{i}\,i\,\displaystyle B_{i,j-i}$ with $T(j)$.
Then your first question becomes: "does $\left(\sum_{j=0}^{N}y^{j}S(j)\right)^2 + \left(\sum_{j=0}^{N}y^{j}T(j)\right)^2$ equal $\left(\sum_{j=0}^{N}y^{j} \right)^2(S(j)^2 + T(j)^2)$?"

Answer (score 3):

No, even without the overall square you cannot factor
$$\displaystyle\left(\sum_{j=0}^{N}y^{j}\left(\sum_{i=0}^{j}k^{i}\,i\,\displaystyle A_{i,j-i}\right)\right)=\left(\sum_{j=0}^{N}y^{j}\right)\left(\sum_{i=0}^{j}k^{i}\,i\,\displaystyle A_{i,j-i}\right)$$
as each term in the $j$ sum multiplies a different $i$ sum.  It would be like claiming $(ab+cd)=(a+c)(b+d)$

Comment: I hope you are doing well. Suppose that this  expression could be rewritten as $\displaystyle\left(\sum_{m=0}^{N}y^{m}\left(\sum_{n=0}^{N}y^{n}nk^{n}\alpha_{n,m}\right)\right)^{2}+\left(\sum_{m=0}^{N}y^{m}\left(\sum_{n=0}^{N}y^{n}nk^{n}\beta_{n,m}\right)\right)^2$. Based on this, would the factorization be possible?

Comment: I don't see the difference from your original question, though I didn't look carefully.  The problem is that the inner sum depends on $m$.  If it did not, you could factor it out.